# Pagination Not Working for multiple query

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using pagination but is not woking. I have used with `get_queryset()` and it works. Why it is not working in `get_context_view()`

```
class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/users.html'
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        context = super(UserListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['companies'] = Company.objects.exclude(company_is_deleted=True).exclude(company_name='Apollo')
        context['users'] = User.objects.filter(userprofile__user_role__id=2).exclude(
            Q(is_superuser=True) | 
            Q(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True)|
            Q(userprofile__user_company__company_is_deleted=True)
            )
        query = self.request.GET.get('query') 
        if query:
            list_query = context['users']
            context['users'] = list_query.filter(userprofile__user_company__company_name__icontains=query)
        return context
```

Comment: Are you getting error? If so then show us the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TemplateView` does not provide us with pagination. we can use `ListView`. It's not recommended to paginate in `get_context_data` method.
For pagination you should use `get_queryset` method.

Example:

```
class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
  paginate_by = 10  

  def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):   
        queryset = User.objects.filter(userprofile__user_role__id=2).exclude(
            Q(is_superuser=True) | 
            Q(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True)|
            Q(userprofile__user_company__company_is_deleted=True)
            )
        query = self.request.GET.get('query') 
        if query:
            queryset = list_query.filter(
                 userprofile__user_company__company_name__icontains=query)
        return queryset
```

If you use `ListView` then in the template you can access users with name `object_list`.